# How to prove that number is perfect square if the sum of digits or the digit root is 1, 7, 4 or 9

Tags: proof-writing, alternative-proof

I recently need to show this for one problem, and I saw this video on youtube where the creator claims that a number is perfect square if the sum of digits or the digit root (sum of sum of digits and so on..) is 1, 4, 7 or 9.

Here is link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNj2Fr72as8

I'm not sure how to prove this, can you show me how to start writing the proof.

Comment: $10$ is not a perfect square.  Nor is $7$ for that matter.

Comment: I think you mean the opposite claim:  "If a natural number is a perfect square, then its iterated digit sum is one of $\{1,4,7,9\}$."  That direction is true and to prove it, just remark that the iterated digit sum essentially just returns the number $\pmod 9$, and then computing the perfect squares $\mod 9$.